# Readonly PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid, readonly, icustomtypedescriptor

I'm using a PropertyGrid in an application I am writing to allow users to view and sometimes edit instances of my objects. Sometimes the user may have a file open in read/write mode where they can make changes to the file through the property grid. In other cases they may have a file open in read only mode, and should not be able to make any changes to the objects through the PropetyGrid. My classes also have dynamic properties which are returned by implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor. Which is why I really want to take advantage of the built in flexibility of a PropertyGrid control.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to set a Property-grid to a read only mode. If I disable a PropertyGrid this also prevents the user from scrolling the list. So I'm thinking the best way to do this is to add ReadOnlyAttributes to the properties at run-time. Is there some other way?

Comment: You're completely right. Your only way is to add the ReadOnly attribute to each property published by your custom TypeDescriptor. There is no flexible solution with MSPG to get a disabled PropertyGrid which is still scrollable and "property selectable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` there is no need to add any attributes; you can just override `IsReadOnly` on the `PropertyDescriptor`. I'm thinking it should be pretty simple to write an intermediary type that mimics (via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `TypeConverter`) a wrapped type but always returns readonly `PropertyDesciptor` instances? Let me know if you want an example (it isn't *trivial* though).

You might also want to check whether something [like this](http://www.visualhint.com/propertygrid) offers it built it.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking but was hoping their was an easier way. The real problem is sometimes my class is read only and other times it is not. Rather than creating a separate read only wrapper type what about just adding a boolean property to the base type that ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties() checks to see if it should be returning editable or read only properties?

Answer (score 18):

I have found a very quick solution for thoses who do not care about the propertygrid being grayed out.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(myObject, new Attribute[]{new ReadOnlyAttribute(true)});
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myObject;
```

Comment: This is a great one line solution.
Is there a way to undo it in code? I tried looking for a property called "Readonly" on the object after applying your code and it didn't seem to have it.

Comment: @RogerBacon You can undo it the same way `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(myObject, new ReadOnlyAttribute(false));` It's not so elegant, but still it works.

Comment: The disabled color can be changed with `DisabledItemForeColor`. I set it to `ControlText` and now it looks normal again (not grayed out).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up inheriting from PropertyGrid and select the parent category whenever a property is selected.

Simple and no need to use TypeDescriptor.

```
public class ReadOnlyPropGrid : PropertyGrid
{
    public ReadOnlyPropGrid()
    {
        this.ToolbarVisible = false; // categories need to be always visible
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedGridItemChanged(SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSelection.GridItemType == GridItemType.Property)
        {
            if (e.NewSelection.Parent != null && e.NewSelection.Parent.GridItemType == GridItemType.Category)
            {
                this.SelectedGridItem = e.NewSelection.Parent;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, works well enough for me! Simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to write a custom control that inherits from the propertygrid control, and in that custom control, have a boolean value of readonly, and then override some things and check, if(readonly) then cancel the action

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this one.  I wanted a control that was read only but not grayed out.

Inherit from the property grid control and create your own read only version by adding the following code to override key presses

```
#Region "Non-greyed read only support"

Private isReadOnly As Boolean
Public Property [ReadOnly]() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.isReadOnly
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Me.isReadOnly = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If Me.isReadOnly Then Return True
    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
End Function

Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean
    If m.Msg = &H204 Then 'WM_RBUTTONDOWN
        If Me.isReadOnly Then Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
#End Region
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that the IMessageFilter interface must be implemented. 
Anyway, this solution doesn't work since it doesn't prevent the user to click or double-click a dropbox and change (i.e.) a value that way.